# Making audio calls on iPhone via Automator in macOS Sierra

Tags: applescript, audio, automator, facetime, call

I was using this script by [Evan Carmi](https://evancarmi.com/writing/call-with-iphone-from-mac-osx/) to make audio calls via my Mac:

```
on run {input, parameters}
  open location "tel://" & input & "?audio=yes"
  return input
end run
```

This worked great until I recently updated my Mac to macOS Sierra 10.12.5. Now it returns an error (popup window that says "the action run applescript encountered an error"). The script allows any number to be called from any application (see [this](https://evancarmi.com/writing/call-with-iphone-from-mac-osx/)).

Does anyone know how to update this script so that it works on macOS Sierra 10.12.5?

Comment: What error does it return? Add the error message to your question using the edit link.

Comment: The error is just a popup window that says "the action run applescript encountered an error".  Won't let me add another link in the question above nor can i attach an image.  link to image :  http://www.real-estate-agent-sunshine-coast.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Untitled.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

This works for me on the latest version of Sierra

```
set input to "0123456789" -- input real phone number
    open location "tel://" & input & "?audio=yes"
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 36
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I have improved it and added it as Automator Service, so you can access it anywhere:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set my text item delimiters to " "
    set resultList to every text item of input
    set text item delimiters to ""
    set phone to resultList as string
    
    -- 123456789 (test)
    open location "tel://" & phone
    return input
end run
```

[image: Automator/AppleScript Service for Phone calling]